# What is the difference between percentileDisc and percentileCount in Apache Age aggregation functions?

Tags: apache-age

Difference between percentileDisc and percentileCount aggregation functions in Apache AGE.

I am unable to understand the difference between percentileDisc and percentileCount aggregation functions. It says in the documentation that we use percentileDisc  calculates "the nearest value to the percentile. For interpolated values, see percentileCont." Could someone please explain the difference between the two with an example. What result would these two queries give

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (n:Person)
    RETURN percentileCont(n.age, 0.4)
$$) as (percentile_cont_age agtype);
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (n:Person)
    RETURN percentileDisc(n.age, 0.5)
$$) as (percentile_disc_age agtype);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The documentation is clear. https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/aggregate_functions.html . In fact, those are the exact same code examples used in the documentation *with example outputs*.

Answer (score 2):

Both `percentileCont` and `percentileDisc` functions in Apache AGE are used to calculate percentiles, but they do so in slightly different ways. Here's how:

- percentileDisc: This function calculates the discrete percentile.
  Discrete percentile does not interpolate values and will always
  return a value that is present in the given dataset. It returns the
  value below which a given percentage falls into. For example, if you
  want to find out the 50th percentile (median) of ages in your data,
  percentileDisc will return the age at the exact middle of your
  dataset (when sorted in ascending order). If there is an even number
  of data points, it will return the lower of the two middle values.
- percentileCont: This function calculates the continuous percentile.
  Unlike percentileDisc, percentileCont may interpolate between values
  in the dataset when the requested percentile lies between two data
  points. This results in a more "continuous" measure that can provide
  a more accurate picture when the dataset is large.

Let's consider an example dataset of ages: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50.

If you execute percentileDisc(n.age, 0.5), it will return 30 because 30 is the exact middle value of this dataset.

But if you execute percentileCont(n.age, 0.4), it will interpolate between 20 and 30 because the 40th percentile is not exactly on a specific data point. This results in a return value of 24 (0.6 of the way between 20 and 30).

So, the percentileDisc is usually used when you want to find an actual data point in your dataset that represents the Nth percentile, while percentileCont is used when you want to calculate the Nth percentile based on the continuous distribution of your data, even if the resulting value is not an actual data point in your dataset.

Answer (score -1):

Using the data provided by the [AGE documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/aggregate_functions.html) as an example,

```
SELECT create_graph('graph_name');

SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    CREATE (a:Person {name: 'A', age: 13}),
    (b:Person {name: 'B', age: 33, eyes: "blue"}),
    (c:Person {name: 'C', age: 44, eyes: "blue"}),
    (d1:Person {name: 'D', eyes: "brown"}),
    (d2:Person {name: 'D'}),
    (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b),
    (a)-[:KNOWS]->(c),
    (a)-[:KNOWS]->(d1),
    (b)-[:KNOWS]->(d2),
    (c)-[:KNOWS]->(d2)
$$) as (a agtype);
```

### percentileCont

Running the `percentileCont()` function will produce an output:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (n:Person)
    RETURN percentileCont(n.age, 0.4)
$$) as (percentile_cont_age agtype);

 percentile_cont_age
---------------------
 29.0
(1 row)
```

Having taken a look at how the `percentileCont()` is calculated from the '[agtype.c](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/9d06d50cd0a1d5b2ad1bd8ffa6dab6c516ffd155/src/backend/utils/adt/agtype.c#L9196)' file, linear interpolation is calculated where,

```
result = y1 + [(x - x1) * (y2 - y1)] / (x2 - x1)

x = percentile * (number_of_rows - 1) - x1
x1 = floor(percentile * (number_of_rows - 1))
x2 = ceil(percentile * (number_of_rows - 1))
y1 = value_of_x1
y2 = value_of_x2
```

In this example, as `percentile = 0.4` and `number_of_rows = 3` (with ages 13, 33, and 44), this would result to:

```
x = 0.4 * (3 - 1) - 0 = 0.8
x1 = floor(0.4 * (3 - 1)) = floor(0.8) = 0
x2 = ceil(0.4 * (3 - 1)) = ceil(0.8) = 1
y1 = value_of_x1 = 13
y2 = value_of_x2 = 33

result = 13 + [(0.8 - 0) * (33 - 13)] / (1 - 0) = 29
```

Which is exactly what we got when using the `percentileCont()` function.

### percentileDisc

Running the `percentileDisc()` function will produce an output:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (n:Person)
    RETURN percentileDisc(n.age, 0.5)
$$) as (percentile_disc_age agtype);

 percentile_disc_age
---------------------
 33.0
(1 row)
```

This function uses a simpler method of calculation, using a rounding method and calculating the nearest value to the percentile.

```
result = round_to_nearest_val(percentile * (max_val - min_val) + min_val)
```

In this example, as `percentile = 0.5`, `max_val = 44`, and `min_val = 13` (with ages 13, 33, and 44), this would result to:

```
result = round_to_nearest_val(0.5 * (44 - 13) + 13) = round_to_nearest_val(28.5) = 33
```

Which is exactly what we got when using the `percentileDisc()` function.